# Bootstrap slider with slideStop event

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I have a bootstrap slider on my page. I don't know how can I change this code, that the page.php will not be constanly loading while dragging the slider, but only when I stop dragging it (after the desired period of time). Probably I have to use slideStop event, but don't know how.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var intSeconds = 1;
        var refreshId;

        function sTimeout() {
            $("#mydiv").load("page.php"); // load content
            refreshId = setTimeout(function() { // saving the timeout
                sTimeout();
            }, intSeconds *3000);
        }
        sTimeout();
        $.ajaxSetup({cache: false});

        // The slider
        $("#ex1").slider({
            min : 1, // minimum value
            max : 20, // maximum value
            step : 1,
            value : intSeconds, // copy current value
            formater: function(value) { // option to format the values before they are sent to the tooltip
                clearTimeout(refreshId); // clear it
                intSeconds = value; // update value
                sTimeout(); // restart it
                return value*3 + ' s';
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK I'm gonna give this a try.  I guess you are using the bootstrap slider plugin/add-on  https://github.com/seiyria/bootstrap-slider or a similar fork.

So what you would want to do is to firstly cancel the `setTimeout` on `slideStart` and reinstate it on `slideStop`.  However if an ajax request started before the slider was moved and returns during drag you also don't want to update the contents of the div.

The code would go a little like this:

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var intSeconds = 1;
    var refreshId;

    //set a flag so we know if we're sliding
    slideStart = false;
    $('#ex1').slider();
    $('#ex1').on('slideStart', function () {
        // Set a flag to indicate slide in progress
        slideStart = true;
        // Clear the timeout
        clearInterval(refreshId);
    });

    $('#ex1').on('slideStop', function () {
        // Set a flag to indicate slide not in progress
        slideStart = false;
        // start the timeout
        refreshId = setInterval(function () { // saving the timeout
            sTimeout();
        }, intSeconds * 3000);
    });

    //Change the sTimeout function to allow interception of div content replacement
    function sTimeout() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'page.php',
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function (response) {
                if (slideStart) {
                    // slide in progress so bail out.
                    return;
                } else {
                    // slide not in progress so go ahead.
                    $("#mydiv").html(response);
                }
            },
            error: function () {
                // handle your error here
            }
        });
    }


    refreshId = setInterval(function () { // saving the timeout
        sTimeout();
    }, intSeconds * 3000);
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, it looks nice, but without sTimeout() at the beginning the loaded part (page.php) is not visible until I touch the slider. One thing I don't understand is why when I move the slider page.php is loaded many times at once when the value is higher than 1?

Comment: OK Have a look at this test fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/WvsKp/1/ it should do what you need.  I have also updated the answer code.

Comment: Look nice, but in your example slider indicator doesn't update time - it is always 3 seconds. Could you also add to you example slider tooltip information about refresh time?